# Bringing component on JLayeredPane to the front when their listener performs an action

Tags: java, jlayeredpane

I have a `JLayeredPane` and a couple of  separate objects that extend JLabel, which are added to the pane. Said objects have a `MouseListener` added to them and now I want to bring the objects to the front, whenever their listeners performs their action.

I had the idea of referring to the `JLayeredPane` from inside of the added object, but i can't seem to access it from there.

So how would i get the (clicked on/ dragged/ whatever) object infront of the others?

Comment: give content of JLayeredPane reference to pane that contains them.

Comment: sounds like a great solution, how would i do that?